# Scrape urls from search results in Python and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I was trying to scrape some urls from the search result and I tried to include both cookies setting or user-agent as Mozilla/5.0 and so on. I still cannot get any urls from the search result. Any solution I can get this working?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

monitored_tickers = ['GME', 'TSLA', 'BTC']

def search_for_stock_news_urls(ticker):
    search_url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=yahoo+finance+{}&tbm=nws".format(ticker)
    r = requests.get(search_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    atags = soup.find_all('a')
    hrefs = [link['href'] for link in atags]
    return hrefs

raw_urls = {ticker:search_for_stock_news_urls(ticker) for ticker in monitored_tickers}
raw_urls
```

Comment: why dont you use google search api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could be running into the issue that requests and bs4 may not be the best tool for what you're trying to accomplish. As balderman said in another comment, using google search api will be easier.

This code:

```
from googlesearch import search

tickers = ['GME', 'TSLA', 'BTC']
links_list = []
for ticker in tickers:
    ticker_links = search(ticker, stop=25)
    links_list.append(ticker_links)
```

will make a list of the top 25 links on google for each ticker, and append that list into another list.  Yahoo finance is sure to be in that list of links, and a simple parser based on keyword will get the yahoo finance url for that specific ticker.  You could also adjust the search criteria in the search() function to whatever you wish, say ticker + ' yahoo finance' for example.

Answer (score 0):

Google News could be easily scraped with `requests` and `beautifulsoup`. It would be enough to use `user-agent` to extract data from there.

Check out [SelectorGadget](https://selectorgadget.com/) Chrome extension to visually grab `CSS` selectors by clicking on the element you want to extract.

If you only want to extract URLs from Google News, then it's as simple as:

```py
for result in soup.select('.dbsr'):
    link = result.a['href']
# 10 links here..
```

Code and [example that scrape more in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Scrape-Google-News-Python-BS4-Request#main.py):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml

headers = {
    "User-Agent":
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

params = {
    "q": "yahoo finance BTC",
    "hl": "en",
    "gl": "us",
    "tbm": "nws",
}

html = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search', headers=headers, params=params)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')

for result in soup.select('.dbsr'):
    link = result.a['href']
    print(link)

-----
'''
https://finance.yahoo.com/news/riot-blockchain-reports-record-second-203000136.html
https://finance.yahoo.com/news/el-salvador-not-require-bitcoin-175818038.html
https://finance.yahoo.com/video/bitcoin-hovers-around-50k-paypal-155437774.html
... other links
'''
```

---

Alternatively, you can achieve the same result by using [Google News Results API](https://serpapi.com/news-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The differences is that you don't have to figure out how to extract elements, maintain the parser over time, bypass blocks from Google.

Code to integrate:

```py
import os
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
  "engine": "google",
  "q": "coca cola",
  "tbm": "nws",
  "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

for news_result in results["news_results"]:
  print(f"Title: {news_result['title']}\nLink: {news_result['link']}\n")

-----
'''
Title: Coca-Cola Co. stock falls Monday, underperforms market
Link: https://www.marketwatch.com/story/coca-cola-co-stock-falls-monday-underperforms-market-01629752653-994caec748bb
... more results
'''
```

P.S. I wrote a [blog post](https://dev.to/dimitryzub/scrape-google-news-with-python-4o14) about how to scrape Google News (*including pagination*) in a bit more detailed way with visual representation.

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.